# How to return min date on this select having query

Tags: sql-server-2012

Here is the query:

```
  -- Get purchase order ETA for first purchase order whose quantity completes a (running total) sum (within the interval between today's date and some future date) adequate to satisfy current demand
  select min(t2.docduedate) as ETA
  from por1 t1
    inner join opor t2 on t1.docentry = t2.docentry
      join opor t3 on t2.docentry = t3.docentry
        and t3.docduedate <= t2.docduedate
  where t1.itemcode = 'NSL1705-S'
    and t2.docduedate > getdate()
  group by t1.itemcode
  --         , t1.dscription
          , t2.docduedate
  having (select sum(t6.quantity)
            from por1 t6
              inner join opor t7 on t6.docentry = t7.docentry
            where t7.docduedate <= t2.docduedate
              and t7.docduedate > getdate()
              and t6.itemcode = 'NSL1705-S') >= 141
```

Here are the results:

```
ETA
2016-02-17 00:00:00.0
2016-02-24 00:00:00.0
2016-03-02 00:00:00.0
2016-04-11 00:00:00.0
```

I want it to return only the row with the min date:

```
ETA
2016-02-17 00:00:00.0
```

What am I missing? The 'min(t2.docduedate)' bit obviously isn't working the way I hoped.

Note: this is actually a subquery as part of a larger query and so I can't use anything that can't be used in a subquery to solve this problem.

Update (thanks to 500 Internal Server error), this works:

```
  select min(t2.docduedate) as ETA
  from por1 t1
    inner join opor t2 on t1.docentry = t2.docentry
      join opor t3 on t2.docentry = t3.docentry
        and t3.docduedate <= t2.docduedate
  where t1.itemcode = 'NSL1705-S'
    and t2.docduedate > getdate()
    and (select sum(t6.quantity)
            from por1 t6
              inner join opor t7 on t6.docentry = t7.docentry
            where t7.docduedate <= t2.docduedate
              and t7.docduedate > getdate()
              and t6.itemcode = 'NSL1705-S') >= 141
```

Comment: What's the result like if you get rid of the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, thanks for the sanity check. Just getting rid of the group by and moving the having condition into the where clause solved the problem. If you want to make your suggestion into an answer I'll accept it. Thanks.